# Dijsktra Graph, Shortest Path

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, dijkstra

I have a problem with a graph. My graph looks like this:

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/wi82ep.png]

The real problem is: I want to find the path with the least amount of "turns" between two points. Here's an example :

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/wbezk3.png]

In this image I draw a simple 3x3 graph, and the shortest path among the red point and the blue point is the green line, because it has only one turn, instead the pink line has 3 turns.

I want to weigh the edges of the graph accordingly and then use Dijsktra's algorithm to find the appropriate path

Comment: Do you have any code you can show?

Comment: if you weigh the horizontall edges as 1 and the vertical ones as 0.999 I think you can obtain a path with just one "turn". But this is just my intuition

Comment: Can't you just go left/right from point A until you are on the same horizontal level as B, and then go up/down until you hit B? Alternatively, go vertical first, then go horizontal. As your graph is resembling a grid, it should not be too hard to have each node contain information about its (x,y) coordinates. No need for weighting all the edges here in my opinion.

Comment: Similar to vivoconunxino's idea, make with [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) with heuristic h1(x,y) = a*x + y and/or h2(x,y) = x + a*y. Where a<1.

Comment: But the graph can contain after some obstacles. So the idea to go vertical and after orizzontal isn't a good idea.

Comment: Use an edge based algorithm and introduce a turn cost function

Comment: I find the solution. A simple edge has a cost of 1, a turn edge has a cost of 2*(H+W) , where H is height of the graph and w the width. Thanks to everybody ;)

Comment: @user3694151 create an answer and check it (accept) so this question moves to solved ones

Answer (score 0):

The key of the solution is that to weigh "turn" operation a high cost. In fact, any value who is larger than W + H is available.
While, I'm guessing whether you need to modify your problem? If all cells of your graph are available, the shortest path between either 2 points are obviously unique and no need to call shortest path algorithm like Dijsktra. If they are in same line, just go straight, if they are not, only needs one turn. So I suggest you add some condition, for example, some points are unreachable, then this problem becomes interesting.